# Can't add reference to Xamarin app in my UWP project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin app for which I want to add a UWP project, so I created the UWP project following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation). However when I reach step 5 to add a reference, I get this error:

> Unable to add a reference to project 'MyProjectName'

where MyProjectName is the name of my main Xamarin app.

How can I add the required reference so I can proceed with setting up the UWP app?

Comment: Have you checked that _Ensure the other projects in the solution are also updated to the same version of the Xamarin.Forms package._? Is _'MyProjectName'_ is .NET standard assembly?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT not yet, I haven't looked at this project in a while, it was sort of an experiment...

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski OK, I did update all Xamarin projects to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms. Now when I go to open up the `MyProjectName` project, I see it is a .NET Framework 4.5.1 project?! I wonder why Xamarin would have created it that way? I used the wizard to create the various projects... Is there any way to convert this project to a .NET Standard project or do I need to start over from scratch?

Comment: @ekolis You can run .NET Portability Analyzer to convert project to .NET Standard or use other option in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/libraries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I figured it out - I was adding a reference to the wrong project! I thought I was adding a reference to the Xamarin project but I was actually adding a reference to the Web API project which was .NET Framework, therefore that is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just add references from other projects by going right click references >> add references from other projects >> select target project >> Add all .NET required assembly. If packages not available to add.

else

Create new Xamarin.Forms project (select UWP,iOS, Android) or create new empty solution and add projects